# Recreating git pushes

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have a odd assignment and I'm not sure how to do this...

I need to look at a public repo and once a day take all the pushes that happened on that repo and re-push them via a single account to another repo.  Kind of like a mirror but more of a re-committing all pushes

Comment: pull from the public server and push to the alternate remote (after adding the additional remote).

Comment: cron job? "enter at least 15 characters"

Comment: *"re-committing all pushes"* doesn't make sense to me. Can you clarify the assignment? To me, it sounds like you want to squash all commits down for a day into one and commit that branch to another repository.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use reset and rebase to do this.

Assuming you have repo.url

```
git clone repo.url
git remote add neworigin newrepo.url
```

Now create branch on local copy

```
git checkout -b myworkbranch
```

1) First time commit by single account

At this moment master and myworkbranch are in sync

Now see the log of all changes done on repo.url and see the first commit , take your head there by using git reset --soft

After that add all the files like you do normal push

```
git add --all
git commit -m "My combined push"
git push neworigin myworkbranch:master
```

This will push all changes in single commit first time , note the commit id

2) Ongoing pull and changes push

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout myworkbranch
git rebase master
git log
```

Now again you are ready to reset

git reset --soft To commit id you noted earlier

```
git add --all
git commit -m "My second combined commit"
git push neworigin myworkbranch:master
```

Keep on repeating

Not tested , but should work.

Comment: Thank you!  Really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've repository already cloned, add another remote to where you want to push, e.g.

```
git remote add mirror git@github.com:foo/bar.git
```

Then pull from `origin` (upstream) and push to another repository, e.g.

```
git pull origin master
git push mirror master
```

Make sure you have appropriate access to push to both repositories.

To check your current configured remotes, run: `git remote -v`.

To do this task once a day, create a script and add its execution to `crontab` or if you're using Linux then copy the script to `/etc/cron.daily` folder (if it's supported by your system).

Comment: Thank you!  Really appreciate it